# Setdate intel XDK bootstrap3 input type date

Tags: intel-xdk

What I am trying to do is select a date with `datepicker` in `week1` then call function `mydateset(wk)` to set date plus 7 days in `week2` input.

My code:

```
<input class="wide-control form-control default" type="date" id="week1"       style="font-weight: bold;" onblur="mydateset('week1')">
<input class="wide-control form-control default" type="date" id="week2"   style="font-weight: bold;">

<script>

    function mydateset(wk) {
        if (wk == 'week1') {
            var tt = document.getElementById('week1').value;
            window.alert("tt is = "+ tt );              
        }
        var ndate = new Date(tt);
        window.alert("date is = "+ ndate);
        var newdate = new Date(ndate);
        window.alert("newdate is = "+ newdate);
        newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 8);

        var dd = newdate.getDate();
        var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
        var y = newdate.getFullYear();

        var someFormattedDate = dd +'/' +mm + '/' + y;
        window.alert("(New date is = "+someFormattedDate );
        //document.getElementById('week2').value = someFormattedDate;
        $('#week2').val(someFormattedDate);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to pad day and month vars with 0 if lest than 10. I had to format string "yyyy-mm-dd" for datepicker to accept date.